# How do you remove quotation marks form a list in python?

Tags: python

```
if deliver == 1 :
    address = list(input("What is your address?"))


print("Your pizza will be delivered to", address)
```

When it prints it does 'p' 'p' 'o' 'p' '1' '1' when i want it to do pp op11 so it can take in real address

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: why do you make the input a list if you want a single string?

Comment: Just remove the `list(...)` call and everything should be fine.

Comment: Why are you calling `list()`? Why do you want the user's input to be a list?

Comment: So it can take both numbers and letters

Comment: What is it you think `list` is doing to allow for that? you'll still end up with a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

So 2 ideas here, I will show you how to fix your current problem and then I will help you see a bigger problem.

## Here is how to fix your current problem.

```py
if deliver == 1 :
    address = list(input("What is your address?"))


print("Your pizza will be delivered to", ''.join(address))
```

Notice the ''.join(address).

.join: tell python to concatenate each item in a list.

.join(list): list is the list that you need to concatenate.

''.join(list): '' tells .join to add nothing between each item in the list

- '-'.join(['888', '123', '4567']) would create '888-123-4567'.

## How to fix the bigger problem.

You are using input() which will return a string.

You then wrapped that string in a list. When a string is turned into a list each character, including spaces are turned into list items.

Once you understand that it may help you understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `list` method is taking the input string, let's say 'Address1' and converting it to ['A', 'd', 'd', 'r', 'e', 's', 's', '1'] that's why you are seeing the quotation marks.

you can do something like this:

```py
print("Your pizza will be delivered to", input("What is your address?"))
```

and avoid extra processing.

Be aware that if `deliver != 1` this code will raise a NameError exception, because (I don't know the rest of your code) but the address variable could not be defined.